# Redirect rule http to https not working when using full url

Tags: asp.net, azure, web-config, http-redirect

My azure cloud service has both http and https enabled in config files.
I tried adding this rule in my web.config

```
<rule name="RedirectHTTPToHTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" ignoreCase="true" />

        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

if I use http://mysite.kom ,it is correctly redirecting to https://mysite.kom

But if I type http://mysite.kom/other/default.aspx  it is  redirecting to *http://mysite.kom/other/default.aspx* **instead of** *https://mysite.kom/other/default.aspx*

I added `GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());` in my application_start event.But still "http://mysite.kom/other/default.aspx" is **not getting redirected** to "**https:**//mysite.kom/other/default.aspx"

I tried all the similar questions in stackoverflow.I even moved the this rule to top of my rules config. Any suggestions to make this working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this , I added

```
if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection && !HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host.Contains("localhost"))
        {
            Response.Redirect("https://" + Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]
                                         + HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
        }
```

to Application_BeginRequest event inside my global.asax.cs file

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use:

```xml
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="redirect HTTP to HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                <add input="{WARMUP_REQUEST}" pattern="1" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

While you aren't preserving the query string, it still seems like you have everything necessary to get http->https redirection.  That makes me wonder if browser caching is causing you problems?  I have had the issue before where I didn't think it was working because I hit the site before enabling http->https redirection and it turned out to be my browser serving up the page from cache.

I wrapped this in a site extension, and it uses the above rewrite rule, so I know it works:
http://www.siteextensions.net/packages/RedirectHttpToHttps/